# meteor: render a template in a specific context

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have two templates

```
<body>
    {{>tmpl1}}
    {{>tmpl2}}
    ....
</body>
```

in the tmpl1 I have a list of items, which can be clicked. When one is click, tmpl2 shown the details. How can this be achieved ?

So, just to make the idea clearer, here is how I get the list of items

```
Template.tmpl1.items = function () {
    return Items.find({}).fetch();
};
```

`tmpl1` displays them as follows

```
<template name="tmpl1">
    {{#each items}}
        {{title}}
    {{/each}}
    ....
</template>
```

So `tmpl2` template might look like this

```
<template name="tmpl1">
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <p>{{content}}</p>
</template>
```

Any suggestions how to link the selected item in `tmpl1` with `tmpl2` ?

Comment: Hrm, have you tried an on click event for tmpl2 that does a Meteor.call (http://goo.gl/esCkl) to grab the subset of data from tmpl1? Or a handlebars helper in tmpl2 that reactively loads whenever a meteor session is changed in tmpl1 - http://goo.gl/wrEXq? 2cents,

Comment: nope, meteor is very new for me. So from what you suggest is that on the `item` click I put something on the `Session` which `tmpl2` will retrieve and displays?

Comment: Do not use `Session` for such purposes: it's the equivalent of a good old global variable. Use template data instead - see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, put your templates in a container so that you can manipulate the context. Also, put the details template in a `#with` context:

```
<template name="box">
  {{> list}}
  {{#with item}}
    {{> details}}
  {{/with}}
</template>
```

Now, add the event handlers for the `box` template. Assuming your entries in the `list` looks like this:

```
<div class="listItem" data-id="{{_id}}">{{title}}</div>
```

Write the handler:

```
Template.box.events({
  'click .listItem': function(e, t) {
    t.data.itemId = $(e.target).data('id');
    t.data.itemDep.changed();
  }
});
```

Finally, create the data helper and dependency for the selected item:

```
Template.box.created = function() {
  this.data.itemDep = new Deps.Dependency();
};

Template.box.item = function() {
  this.itemDep.depend();
  return Items.findOne(this.itemId);
};
```

Comment: Clever. I haven't fully grasped how the dependency object accompanies the data value yet, but I love the clean approach.

Comment: nice solution. At this moment I'm trying to get this idea to work. One thing I'm struggling with right now is that `this.data === undefined`. Any suggestions ?

Comment: I see `this === window`. Also, if I define this.data in one method, its gone in the other :( However, when I define the `data` object on `Template.box.data` it works. Am I missing something here ?

Comment: @gamengineers: It's quite simple, the dependency object can be used to track the changes of anything you want, you just need to 1) call `dep.changed()` whenever you change the tracked object value, and `dep.depend()` in reactive places that should be updated when the value is changed. In this case, I just create an arbitrary dependency object to track the `item` value and store it locally in the template data.

Comment: @JeanlucaScaljeri: I don't fully understand why such things can happen, if you got it to work by defining `Template.data.box`, that's great. I recall that this somehow depends on how the template is called, i.e. whether you call `{{> template}}` in the top level, or within a `{{#each}}` or `{{with}}` block, or via `Template.template()`.

Comment: I have it working :) I did it a little bit different, instead of defining `data` on the Template I created simply a global variable (global means: only visible in the file it is defined in!): `var data = {};`

Comment: One more thing, when I update `data` and call `data.dep.changed()` the view doesn't change. How does this work ?